# Date in milliseconds on OpenWRT on Arduino YUN

Tags: date, busybox, openwrt

I am using OpenWRT on the Arduino YUN and I am trying to get the exact date in milliseconds (DD/MM/YYYY h:min:sec:ms) by getting the time by an timeserver.

Unfortunately `date +%N` just returns `%N`, but not the nanoseconds. I heard `+%N` is not included in OpenWRT date.

So is there any way to get the date (including milliseconds) how I want it?

Comment: Do you have `date --rfc-3339=ns`

Comment: No: `date: unrecognized option --rfc-3339=ns`

Comment: May be `ntptime` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually there is also a package called `coreutils-date`! Didn't know about it! There all standard functionality is included!

Answer (score 10):

On OpenWRT, `date` is `busybox`, which has limitations, but this is not strictly one of them. The underlying problem is that the libc (uClibc) [does not support this GNU strftime extension](http://git.uclibc.org/uClibc/tree/libc/misc/time/time.c#n31). (Though neither does glibc, more on that below.)

You should have `lua` by default, but that [won't help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463101/lua-current-time-in-milliseconds) without some other non-default modules.

`hwclock` calls `gettimeofday()` for comparing/setting the RTC (hardware clock), but it won't output sub-second resolution (accessing RTCs can be sufficient slow that it might not be useful anyway). Other than that OpenWRT only provides the ancient `rdate`, which only has whole-second resolution.

There appears to be no straightforward way to get an accurate time stamp directly from `/proc`, the most useful time stamp is in `/proc/timer_list` (3rd line) which is the uptime in nanoseconds (the resolution will depend on the platform).

If your busybox was built with `CONFIG_BUSYBOX_CONFIG_ADJTIMEX` set, then you should be able to use `adjtimex` to read the kernel clock (though note that the busybox version has *both* different arguments and different output to the standard adjtimex.

Normal version, `adjtimex -p`, last line of output:

```
   raw time:  1416419719s 146628us = 1416419719.146628
```

Busybox version, `adjtimex` (without `-p` !), last 3 lines:

```
   [...]
   time.tv_sec:  1416420386
   time.tv_usec: 732653
   return value: 0 (clock synchronized)
```

Goldilocks's is a fine solution, assuming you have your OpenWRT cross build setup (highly recommended!).
Your *coreutils-date* solution works because while coreutils is glibc aware, it is not exclusively glibc. It comes with its own standalone implementation of `strftime` (derived from glibc), and uses that to wrap up (via `strftime_case()`) the underlying `strftime` so as to support various extensions (and falls back to the uClibc version otherwise).

Even glibc (up to the current 2.23) doesn't support `%N`, the coreutils `strftime()` derived from the canonical glibc version adds `%N` and `%:z` and a few other changes. Variations and patched versions of `strftime()` abound (including versions in bash and gawk).

Comment: Thanks.  `awk 'NR==3 {print $3}' /proc/timer_list` came in handy for me when I needed finer resolution time than any of these utilities granted under the build I'm using.

Comment: The `/proc/timer_list` 3rd line works for me. Not using openwrt, just an embedded linux on busybox.

Comment: My OpenWRT router doesn't have `/proc/timer_list` and also lacks an `adjtimex` command, but I was able to use `/proc/uptime` for 100th-second resolution and `logread -t` for millisecond resolution; see [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/496783/87770) below. No extra packages or compilation needed.

Comment: `adjtimex | grep -i tv | cut -d: -f2 | sed 's/^ *//g' | tr '\n' '.' | sed 's/.$/\n/'`
Produces `1649180458.33628`

Answer (score 6):

If you have a C compiler on it and can't find anything else, this will report, e.g.

```
> millitime && sleep 1 && millitime
14/11/2014 9:39:49:364
14/11/2014 9:39:50:368
```

```c
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <time.h>

int main (void) {
    struct timeval now;
    struct tm *parsed;

    if (gettimeofday(&now, NULL) == -1) {
        fprintf (
            stderr,
            "gettimeofday() failed: %s\n",
            strerror(errno)
        );
        return 1;
    }

    parsed = localtime((const time_t*)&now.tv_sec);
    if (!parsed) {
        fprintf (
            stderr,
            "localtime() failed: %s\n",
            strerror(errno)
        );
        return 1;
    }

    printf (
        "%d/%d/%d %d:%02d:%02d:%03d\n",
        parsed->tm_mday,
        parsed->tm_mon + 1,
        parsed->tm_year + 1900,
        parsed->tm_hour,
        parsed->tm_min,
        parsed->tm_sec,
        now.tv_usec / 1000
    );

    return 0;
}
```

With gcc, just compile it `gcc whatever.c -o millitime`.  If there's an error (which would be very weird), it reports to stderr and exits with a status of 1.  Otherwise it reports to stdout and exits 0.

The milliseconds are **rounded down** from microseconds.

Answer (score 2):

I've found that I can get timing information to the hundredth of a second from `/proc/uptime` in an embedded Linux system with busybox, though converting it to an epoch time is hard because I cannot find any record of the boot time.

Here's some quick sh code:

```bash
read UPTIME < /proc/uptime
UPTIME="${UPTIME%%[^0-9.]*}"
```

If all you need is a timer with precision to 100ths of seconds, this is good enough (time zero, your local epoch, will merely be the time the system booted).

Otherwise, you can cheat and trigger a log entry:

```bash
printf '\u04' |nc $HOSTNAME 22 >/dev/null 2>&1 # trigger log entry by poking ssh
LOG="$(logread -l 1 -t)"                       # read last log entry w/ timestamp
LOG="${LOG##* 20?? \[}"                        # remove text before timestamp
echo "${LOG%%\]*}"                             # remove text after timestamp
```

This consumes 0.026s (median; min=0.025s, max=0.028s, out of 12 runs). Also note that it does pollute your logs ... and I don't know what happens when the logs get "too big" (for whatever value that is); keep in mind logs are stored in memory.

Therefore, if you're going to be polling the time a lot, you should probably only create one bad log entry at the beginning and combine the two above methods as follows:

```bash
get_uptime_ms() {
  local MS
  read UPTIME < /proc/uptime
  UPTIME="${UPTIME%%[^0-9.]*}" # strip the other listed time
  MS="${UPTIME##*.}0"          # extra zero turns 100ths of seconds into 1000ths
  UPTIME="${UPTIME%%.*}$MS"    # the time since boot in milliseconds
}

get_uptime_ms
printf '\u04' |nc $HOSTNAME 22 >/dev/null 2>&1  # poke ssh to trigger log entry 
NOW="$(logread -l 1 -t)"                        # last log entry, with timestamp
NOW="${NOW#* 20?? \[}"                          # remove text before timestamp
NOW="${NOW%%\]*}"                               # remove text after timestamp
MS="${NOW##*.}"                                 # just the milliseconds
NOW="${NOW%%.*}$MS"                             # append ms to s w/out dot

BOOT=$(( NOW - UPTIME ))

date_ms() {
  local S
  get_uptime_ms
  NOW=$(( BOOT + UPTIME))
  S="${NOW%???}"           # $NOW in seconds
  echo "$S.${NOW#$S}"      # put the dot back in, then append milliseconds
}

# now you can run date_ms as much as you like
# and it'll have the epoch time with millisecond precision.

date_ms
date +%s
date_ms
```

This establishes something to use as the original boot time by subtracting the uptime (to 100th of a second) from the log trigger's timestamp (precise to 1000th of a second) and then updates it with the uptime. This therefore yields 100ths of a second rather than 1000ths, but it only injects one extra entry into logd and the other method isn't much more precise since it costs 0.026s to run. (It's decently consistent on my system, so you could consider running it a bunch of times and subtracting that value.)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
void main (void){
    long            ms; 
    time_t          s; 

    struct timespec spec;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &spec);
    s  = spec.tv_sec;
    ms = (spec.tv_nsec / 1.0e6); 
    printf("%d%03d\n", s, ms);      
return 0;
}
```

This in the C language and works like coreutils-date `date +%s%3N`. It is compiled to OpenWrt router with OpenWrt-SDK.

Answer (score 0):

The `adjtimex` solution didn't work for me because I get `adjtimex: Operation not permitted` (I'm using an alpine docker container). But I found another bizarre but dependency-free solution using `nmeter` which can display up to microseconds.

```
#-d0 means print every 0 seconds ie immediately
# head -n1 makes sure it only does it once
nmeter -d0 '%3t' | head -n1
```

So combining this with the date command:

```
date -u +%FT$(nmeter -d0 '%3t' | head -n1)Z
# 2017-05-03T04:10:57.863Z
```

We get a rfc3339 UTC datetime string with milliseconds!